# Starting new background GUI login session or loginwindow on OS X, CGSCreateLoginSessionWithDataAndVisibility function

Tags: macos, cocoa, core-graphics, launchd

I'm writting remote login app and I want to include the possibility to start new GUI session for different user. Goal is similar to what is done on **Screen Sharing.app** when user (different than already logged in) is connected - he can create new desktop without messing with session currently displayed. Is there an API for this? Maybe could You give me some useful links? I can't find anything to point me to the right direction so far.

Edit:
I am already able to connect to running "background" GUI sessions. Now I want to have a possibility to create session for user which is not logged in yet.

Edit: Spawning `loginwindow` under `WindowServer` process will also do the trick. When only one user is logged in, `loginwindow` process is terminated. Additionally - maybe there's a possibility to prevent `loginwindow` termination?

Edit:
I've tracked down function from private **API** which executes new `loginwindow` process under `WindowServer` and it works OK. Function is called `CGSCreateLoginSessionWithDataAndVisibility`, the problem is -  this is private function I don't know what parameters it takes. Now I call it like this:

```
CGSSessionID outSession = 1;
CGSCreateLoginSessionWithDataAndVisibility(&outSession, NULL, false);
```

Does anyone know what arguments are used in `CGSCreateLoginSessionWithDataAndVisibility` or is there another way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 0):

Short of reverse engineering fast user switching and some hackage, I'm not too sure this could be accomplished. AFAIK there are not any public APIs other than some notifications and session states that can be observed for when the user switches users. Some info [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPMultipleUsers/BPMultipleUsers.html) on how to observe those notifications (you can do it through Cocoa or Carbon) and how to fetch the current sessions information.

Hope this helps, sorry for not being more helpful!

Comment: Thank You, but I'm looking for a way to create new session. I am able to connect to already logged in user (seen via fast user switch menu). I'll edit my question to be more specific.

Comment: @MateuszSzlosek Right, AFAK this is the best information on that subject. If you want to log into a new user session you need to figure out how to interact with the fast user switching system (which thus is going to interact with the loginwindow allowing one to login).